# SQL operations on all columns of a table

Tags: sql

I have many (>48) columns in one table, each column corresponds to a month and contains sales for that month. I need to create another table in which each column equals the addition of the previous 12 columns, e.g. getting the "rolling year" figure, so that e.g. July 2010 has everything from August 2009 through July 2010 added, August 2010 has everything from September 2009 through August 2010, and so on.

I could write this as:

```
select   
[201007TOTAL] = [200908] + [200909] + ... + [201007]
,[201008TOTAL] = [200909] + ... + [201008]
...
...

into #newtable
from #mytable
```

I was wondering if there was a smarter way of doing this, either creating these as new columns in the table in one step, or perhaps pivoting the data, doing something to it, and re-pivoting?

Comment: If you can possibly change that table structure, that's really the correct way to go.  You should have another table to hold those months.  Think vertical rather than horizontal.  Your whole structure will be much more manageable and scalable.

Comment: "a smarter way of doing this" would be to use a better data model in which your columns do not play the role of records. It is 2014, and people still struggle with databases that would have gotten DBAs fired in the days of the mainframes.

Comment: I have to agree - years and months should not be column names. But if you have to stick with this layout for some reason, this soluation is as good as any.

Comment: Thanks a lot to all. I eventually need to copy-paste the data into that column format, but for these manipulations I will try to use a different structure until I get my final result.

Comment: If you store everything correctly you can just pivot that data in your final select and end up with the result set in the column format that you need. Not only will you be able to more easily use the data you won't have to add a new column every month and your results can be dynamic and only show the months that are relevant at the time.

Answer (score 1):

Altough everybody is right, a different database set-up would be best, I thought this was a nice problem to play around with. Here's my setup:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST
(
    ID          INT
,   [201401]    decimal(19, 5)
,   [201402]    decimal(19, 5)
,   [201403]    decimal(19, 5)
,   [201404]    decimal(19, 5)
,   [201405]    decimal(19, 5)
,   [201406]    decimal(19, 5)
,   [201407]    decimal(19, 5)
)

INSERT INTO TEST
VALUES (1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

Just one record with data is enough to test.

On the assumption the columns to be summed are consecutive in the table, and the first one is the first with datatype decimal. In other words, the table 'starts' (for want of better word) with a PK, which is usually INT, may be followed by descriptions or whatever, followed by the monthly columns to be summed:

```
DECLARE @OP_START INT
,       @OP_END INT
,       @LOOP INT
,       @DATE VARCHAR(255)
,       @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT '
,       @COLNAME VARCHAR(MAX)

--      Set Date to max date (=columnname)
SET     @DATE = '201406'
--      Find Last attribute
SET     @OP_END =   (
                        SELECT  MAX(ORDINAL_POSITION) 
                        FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                        WHERE   TABLE_NAME = 'TEST'
                            AND COLUMN_NAME <= @DATE
                    )
--      Find First attribute
SET     @OP_START = (
                        SELECT  MIN(ORDINAL_POSITION)
                        FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                        WHERE   TABLE_NAME = 'TEST'
                            AND DATA_TYPE = 'DECIMAL'
                    )

SET     @LOOP = @OP_START

--      Loop through the columns
WHILE   @LOOP <= @OP_END
BEGIN
        SET @COLNAME =  (
                            SELECT      COLUMN_NAME
                            FROM        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                            WHERE       TABLE_NAME = 'TEST'
                                    AND ORDINAL_POSITION = @LOOP
                        )
--      Build SQL with found ColumnName
        SET @SQL = @SQL + '[' + @COLNAME + ']' + '+'

        SET @LOOP = @LOOP + 1
END

--      Remove last "+"
SET     @SQL = SUBSTRING(@SQL, 1, LEN(@SQL) - 1)
--      Complete SQL
SET     @SQL = @SQL + ' FROM TEST'

--      Execute
EXEC(@SQL)
```

This should keep adding up the monthly values, regardless how many you add. Just change the max date to what pleases you.

I'm NOT saying this is the best way to go, but it is a fun way :P